# VMWare VDI Low speed. (низкое быстродействие)

Tags: vmware

Есть проблема с быстродействием в *VNWare* кластере. Периодически виртуальные рабочие места впадают в кому:
от задержки отображения символов на экране при наборе,
до открытия офисных фалов по несколько минут.
Скорость копирования между дисками то 35Мб то 0,1Мб.
Привязать к чему-либо не удалось.
В нерабочее время (2-6 пользователей) проблема отсутствует.
В рабочее время проблема появляется спонтанно и спонтанно пропадает.

Конфигурация:

Кластер:
Сервера: DELL R720 (CPU 2xIntel Xeon E5-2680v2 2.8GHz, RAM: 2 сервера по 192Gб, один 256G, AMD FirePro S9000 (share), Intel X520 DP 10Gb DA / SFP) x3
СХД: EMC VNXe3300 (SAS7200 12x3T RAID6 4x10G LAN)
Сеть: кластер Сisco 4500x 16x10G x2
подключение каждого из серверов к сети: 2x10G общий трафик; 2x10G iSCSI трафик к СХД

установлено:
ESXi 5.5 HA DRS
VMWare Horizon View Standard 6
два VDI пула:
ВМ Windows8.1Pro 2CPU 4G (40 ВМ)
ВМ Windows8.1Pro 4CPU 8G (20 ВМ)
ВМ запущены все, одновременно используется 40-50
ВМ серверов Windows2012R2 DC

кроме серверов инфраструкуры есть несколько вспомогательных.

Как определить и устранить причины такой спонтанной потери производительности?